# How to move the ion-popover up containing form when user focus on the input field which is hidden under the Keyboard in Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I working on an Ionic 5 application. I have a form on the ion-popover component. The ion-popover component which has input fields appears on the center of the screen when it triggered. So when i focus on last input field, the keypad of the mobile comes above and hide the input field.

How to change ion-popover position on focus on last input field. Is the there any easy solution for this.

Expected Result: When the user clicks on input field, the user should be able to see what is typed.

Comment: pass `this.popoverController.create({event: ev}),` in .ts file

Comment: Yes i configured popover controller like above, what should i pass to the event property. what is `ev`? How this helps in moving the popover up.

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/62485729/10805479

Comment: i understood the link you shared. My use case is different, i don't want to place the popover relate to the button clicked. My popover will always be in center, i want to move up when the keyboard opens up when user click on the input field present inside popover to avoid getting hidden. I found an example, need to look to implement on popover. https://ionicframework.com/blog/keyboard-improvements-for-ionic-apps/#:~:text=Ionic%20Keyboard%20Events,the%20keyboard%20height%20in%20pixels.